# How to register FUSE filesystem type with mount(8) and fstab?

Tags: linux, filesystems, gnu, mount, fuse

I've written a small FUSE-based filesystem and now the only part's missing is that I want to register it with fstab(5) to auto-mount it on system startup and/or manually mount it with just `mount /srv/virtual-db`. How can I achieve this?

I know, I can just run `/usr/bin/vdbfs.py /srv/virtual-db` from some init script, but that's not exactly pretty.

I'm sorry because this may be not exactly a programming question, but it's highly related, as the packaging and deployment is still the programmer's job.

Comment: Good question, but not programming related and there is serverfault.com now.

Comment: If that's only administrative problem (like adding an entry to some file), then, yes, probably. But registering in-kernel filesystems are certainly a programming problem (the only admin part is adding module to modprobe.conf), and I don't know about FUSE... So, I don't know where this really belongs.

Comment: Oh this belongs on SO, definitely!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In general, one "registers" a new mount filesystem type by creating an executable `mount.fstype`.

```
$ ln -s /usr/bin/vdbfs.py /usr/sbin/mount.vdbfs
```

If `vdbfs.py` takes `mount`-ish arguments (i.e. `dev path [-o opts]`), then `mount -t vdbfs` and using `vdbfs` as the 3rd field in `fstab` will work.  If it doesn't, you can create a wrapper which does take arguments of that form and maps them to whatever your `vdbfs.py` takes.

FUSE should also install a `mount.fuse` executable; `mount.fuse 'vdbfs.py#dev' path -o opts` will go on and call `vdbfs.py dev path -o opts`.  In that case, you can use `fuse` as your filesystem type and prefix your device with `vdbfs.py#`.

Comment: Note that FUSE's author – *Miklos Szeredi* – [deprecated](https://lwn.net/Articles/221779/) encoding the real filesystem type in the mount source. Quote from [`mount`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) manual: *The programs mount and umount support filesystem subtypes. The subtype is defined by a '.subtype' suffix. For example  'fuse.sshfs'. It's recommended to use subtype notation rather than add any prefix to the mount source (**for  example 'sshfs#example.com' is deprecated**).*

Answer (score 26):

So to clarify ephemient's answer, there are two options:

1. Edit `/etc/fstab` like this:

   ```
   # <file system>   <mount point>      <type>  <options>         <dump>  <pass>
   # ...
   vdbfs.py#<dev>    /srv/virtual-db    fuse    user,<other-opts>    0    0
   ```

   Or,
2. Create an executable prefixed with "mount." (ensuring it can be used
   with `mount`-like options):

   ```
   $ ln -s /usr/bin/vdbfs.py /usr/sbin/mount.vdbfs
   ```

   And edit `/etc/fstab` like this:

   ```
   # <file system> <mount point> <type>    <options>         <dump>  <pass>
   # ...
   <dev>    /srv/virtual-db    vdbfs.py    user,<other-opts>    0    0
   ```

With regards to auto-mounting at start up and manually mounting with `mount`, the `user` and `noauto` options are relevant and fully supported by fuse itself so you don't have to implement them yourself. The `user` option lets a non-priveleged user who is a member of the "fuse" group mount your filesystem with the `mount` command, and `noauto` directs your filesystem not to automatically mount at startup. If you don't specify `noauto`, it will automatically mount.

Answer (score 6):

To clarify @patryk.beza comment on the accepted answer, the *correct way* to mount a FUSE file system is by setting the file system type to `fuse.<subtype>`.

For example, to mount an [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) implementation, which does not provide a specific `/sbin/mount.*` wrapper and uses normally the `s3fs` user command to mount S3 buckets, one can use this command as root:

```
mount -t fuse.s3fs bucket-name /path/to/dir -o <some,options>
```

or this line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
bucket-name /path/to/dir fuse.s3fs <some,options> 0 0
```

or this SystemD mount unit (for example, `/etc/systemd/system/path-to-dir.mount`):

```
[Unit]
Description=S3 Storage
After=network.target

[Mount]
What=bucket-name
Where=/path/to/dir
Type=fuse.s3fs
Options=<some,options>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

How this works: `mount` recognizes the concept of "filesystem subtypes" when the type is formatted with a period (i.e. `<type>.<subtype>`), so that a type with the format `fuse.someimpl` is recognized to be the responsibility of the FUSE mount helper `/sbin/mount.fuse`. The FUSE mount helper then resolves the `someimpl` part to the FUSE implementation, in the same way as the `#` format is used in the original answer (I think this is just a path search for a program named `<subtype>`, but I'm not 100% sure about it).

Answer (score 2):

You could just use fuse filesystem type. The following works on my system:

```
smbnetfs    /media/netbios    fuse    defaults,allow_other    0    0
```

Another example:

```
sshfs#user@example.com:/    /mnt    fuse    user,noauto    0    0
```

Comment: This begs another question: How do I register a custom application with FUSE as a filesystem provider?

Comment: Actually, [this still requires](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/wiki/FAQ#is-it-possible-to-mount-a-fuse-filesystem-from-fstab) adding the `mount.type` solution [mentioned by ephemient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1555146/712526).

Answer (score 0):

After researching a lot found this solution to mount fuse filesystem suing `fstab` entry. I was using fuse for s3bucket to mount on local linux machine.

- `.passwd-s3fs` : Is containing credentials to access your aws account 1] Secret key and 2] Access Key .
- `uid` : User Id. You can type linux command `id` and you can get uid

Syntax:

```
s3fs#<Bucket_Name> <Mounted_Direcotry_Path> fuse _netdev,allow_other,passwd_file=/home/ubuntu/.passwd-s3fs,use_cache=/tmp,umask=002,uid=<User_Id> 0 0
```

Example:

```
s3fs#myawsbucket /home/ubuntu/s3bucket/mys3bucket fuse _netdev,allow_other,passwd_file=/home/ubuntu/.passwd-s3fs,use_cache=/tmp,umask=002,uid=1000 0 0
```

To mount you need run following command.

```
mount -a
```

To check your bucket is mounted properly or not use following command to check which shows all mounted points.

```
df -h
```